# Kubernetes - How to create one Pod per Node?

Tags: kubernetes, statefulset, kubernetes-statefulset

I want a Kubernetes StatefulSet with:

- Number of Replicas/Pods = Number of Nodes in Kubernetes Cluster
- One Pod on on every node

Is there a simple example on how to solve this typical requirement?

Comment: You can use daemonset for this requirement instead of statefulsets. Daemonset provides you a pod on each node. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DaemonSets are exactly what you're looking for. They're a tool which will run a single Pod on every node for your resource. If a new node is created - a new Pod is created on it.

You can find further information onto how they're implemented at the following URL in the documentation:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/

Comment: What if OP (or me actually) needs a stateful set for some of gurantees it provides (ex stable, unique network identifiers or ordered, automated rolling updates.)

Comment: I think --max-pods can also be used to limit the no of pod. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60278561/increase-max-pod-on-node